# Replace many data-tags with one JSON string in html/jquery

Tags: jquery, json

I have a habit of using lots of `data` tags, and then reading them one at a time in jQuery e.g.

```
*html*
<span data-group="1" data-item="2" data-user="abc" data-type="4" . . . . . </span>

*jQuery*
getItemSelected = function($in){dataItem=$in.data("item");}
```

But I'm wondering if there may be a better way than creating an ever increasing number of data tags, by using one tag with json as the content. But so far all my attempts at this have failed.

I'm thinking something like the following:

```
*html*
<span data-options='[{"group":"1","item":"2","user":3". . . .}]'></span>

*jQuery*
getOptions = function($in)
{
dataOptions=jQuery.parseJSON( $in.data("options") );
alert(dataOptions === "group");
}
```

But every variation I have tried so far simply comes up as `undefined`. What is the correct way of doing this?

Comment: Try `$in.data("options")[0].group`. You've made your JSON represent an array by using `[` and `]`. Also, jQuery's `data` function will automatically parse JSON in `data-` attributes

Comment: ```<span data-options='{"group":"1","item":"2","user":3". . . .}'></span>```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a data attribute contains valid json, jQuery `data()` will automatically parse it for you.

```js
$('span[data-options]').each(function(){
    const opts = $(this).data('options');        
    console.log('Type:', typeof opts)
    console.log(opts);
    console.log( '-----------');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span data-options='{"group":"1","item":"2","user":"3"}'></span>
<span data-options='{"group":"2","item":"3","user":"4"}'></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to transfer are multiple distinct single values (like a `group`, `item`, `user`, `type`), the JSON should be just an object rather than an array of objects.

Also, rather than putting everything into an attribute, you may find it easier to manage to put it as the *text content* of an invisible tag, like a non-runnable `<script>` tag:

```js
const data = JSON.parse(document.querySelector('#data-tag').textContent);
console.log(
  data.group,
  data.user
);
```

```html
<script type="application/json" id="data-tag">
{"group":"1","item":"2","user":"3"}
</script>
```

No jQuery needed.